# How to check if my iPhone app is influenced by xcodeGhost?

Tags: xcode

One year ago I downloaded my Xcode from a third-party source and I'm afraid that if my app has been influenced by the xcodeGhost. Can somebody tell me how to check it?

Comment: here is the list of all the infected apps: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-you-need-to-know-about-ios-malware-xcodeghost.1918784/#post-21896151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XcodeGhost adds an extra `CoreServices.framework` at:

> Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/Library/Frameworks/

to an infected Xcode.

Comment: Yeah this is an approach. I've detected my app by capturing the data it sent via Charles. Thankfully it hasn't been affected.

Comment: If I just delete my current affected xcode and install from official one, will it be okay?

Comment: @KhantThuLinn Sure. In fact, you'd most likely receive an email from Apple today to remind developers only download Xcode from the official site.

Answer (score 2):

You can check wether your copy of Xcode contains malicious software by verifying it's code signature:

`codesign -vv /Applications/Xcode.app`

The code signature will fail verification if Xcode has been tampered with and it will list the files that are suspect.

More information [here](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/129539561792/detecting-wether-your-xcode-contains-xcodeghost)

Comment: This solution seems more robust

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry,xcodeGhost was writen early this year.If you download Xcode one year ago,your Xcode  is totally fine.

For more informations , you can check on [xcodeGhost](http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2015/09/novel-malware-xcodeghost-modifies-xcode-infects-apple-ios-apps-and-hits-app-store/)

Answer (score 0):

To go save you can prevent xCodeGhost anyway with a little script in your project. The first version of xCodeGhost is easy to detect:

- You need a file with possible xcodeghost links
- You need a script to search for this links in your whole project (with grep)

To read more aboutxcodeghost v1, just look at: 
https://possiblemobile.com/2015/11/a-lesson-in-xcode-ghost-third-party-frameworks

For v2 of xcodeghost, its not easy as v1, because the links will be generated on a later point of building of app - therefore the only way to detect this is to check your app network acitivity (e.g. with wireshark). Detecting on everything which is not a usual communication of your app. This gives you the possibility to see which frameworks also will communicate with the internet.

The newest version 2 of xcodeghost, you can read here a little bit more:
http://prog3.com/article/2015-11-11/2826185-a-lesson-in-xcode-ghost-third-party-frameworks

Also important if you really want to protect your app/project: Do every test on real device (even analyizing network connection, therefore just give your device a network connection over your macbook (mobile hotspot), this will give you the permission to check explicitely the network connection of your device). Because some hackers are also adding testscripts on 3rd party framework to detect if its on simulator or device.